# Angled in drop bars like Salsa Woodchippers with slightly less angle in?

Tags: handlebars

I like drop compact drop bars but I think I'd like them better if they were angled in like Salsa Woodchipper bars. I adjust my brake levers to angle in on regular drop bars and compact drops because like my hand to grip something at an inward angle, not a straight ahead parallel.

I want to try those Salsa Woodchipper bars, but I'd prefer to first try something less extreme, like a cross between the Salsa Woodchipper and the compact drop bars I use now. Anyone know of such an animal?

(I ride more or less upright, saddle about the same height as the top of the bars. Slow, steady, but sensual. And classy.)

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but the "angle"  you are referring to is more commonly termed "flare."   Many manufactures are starting to add flare to their drop bars for mixed terrain riding.

Answer (score 4):

The Salsa Cowchipper! http://salsacycles.com/components/category/road_handlebars/cowchipper

[image]
Handy comparison image from the salsacycles.com website, in case it ever vanishes from the web.

More information here: http://salsacycles.com/culture/introducing_cowchipper_handlebar

On a sidenote: Maybe your current bar is too narrow? It should be about as wide as your shoulders.

Comment: Excellent! I didn't know they had 3 varieties of those angled bars. That cowchipper might be just what I want.

Comment: The Cowchippers are a new release. Just this summer I believe.

Answer (score 2):

3T and FSA both make compact bend drop bars that have some flare (usually about 6*).  Nowhere near as much as the Salsa offerings - might work if you just want to make a small fit change.